# ORA-00911: invalid character Error

Tags: oracle11g, ora-00911

```
DROP TABLE employee CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE employee (
fname    varchar2(15) not null, 
minit    varchar2(1),
lname    varchar2(15) not null,
ssn      char(9),
bdate    date,
address  varchar2(30),
sex      char,
salary   number(10,2),
superssn char(9),
dno      number(4),
);
```

Hello, could anyone tell me why I receive

```
ORA-00911: invalid character Error
```

When I try to run this code in Oracle Application Express 11g?

Thank you!

Comment: This is old but wanted to say that I get this when I include a ; at the end of my query. Since the oci adds this for you it does not like when you add it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have an extra comma after the last line:

```
dno      number(4), -- <<=== Here
```

Removing it should fix the problem ([link to a demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4f36)).

Comment: @Adam The problem is not coming from that declaration then: I tried it on sqlfiddle with Oracle 11g R2, and the table creation went fine.

Comment: DROP TABLE employee CASCADE CONSTRAINTS; which helped , and cleaned error